# Xcode 4 Assistant editor

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.2, xcode-storyboard

When I open the storyboard file after adding the controls and open the Assistant Editor to begin adding outlets I always get the message "No Assistant Results" !

I tried to restart the application but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you use the jump bar to select things manually?

Comment: it gives me error when using the manual option saying "couldn't find information about class xxxx"

Comment: I also get the same error, can't get it to work...

Comment: I found a solution that I need to save the ViewCOntroller.h /.m first then it will work.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. That worked. For others.. just add some whitespace to your .h file and save it again. Seems to reset something. BTW my problem started after I refactored (renamed) my VC

Answer (score 4):

I opened "Organizer" / "Projects" / Select your project.
Then, I clicked on "Delete" for derived data.

I also restarted XCode but maybe that just deleting derived data without a restart is fine.

Comment: This worked for me... My UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate got messed up due to SVN, and so I got into the problem, but your answer fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove initWithNibName method from your controller.

That solved my issue

Comment: It helped me too, but I have no idea why. I have other controllers with this method and assistant does show automatic results, but for this one it showed results only after I deleted `initWithNibName`.